# Formal Letter with distinct header - footer look depending on page length

Tags: luatex, fancyhdr, update

I am trying to write a formal letter. The issue I am having is utilising `fancyhdr` properly. I would like to achieve the following:

---

- If only a single page:

  - The header and footer only - without page number.

---

- If more than one page:

  - a specific header for the first page
  - a specific footer on the last page
  - page numbering on all pages

---

The code is included.

```
 % !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[ddmmmyyyy]{datetime} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{first-page}{
      \fancyhf{}% No header/footer
    \fancyhead[C]{ABC}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}% Right footer
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% No header rule
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% A footer rule
    }
}

\fancypagestyle{default}{
    \fancyhf{}% No header/footer
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}% Right footer
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% A footer rule
}

\fancypagestyle{last-page}{
      \fancyhf{}% No header/footer
    \fancyfoot[C]{ABC}% Centre footer
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}% Right footer
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% A footer rule
}

\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{first-page}}
\AtEndDocument{\thispagestyle{last-page}}
\begin{document}

\raggedleft
\today

\normalsize Receiver\leavevmode \\ \small Address \leavevmode \\ \small Etc \leavevmode%

\raggedright        

        \normalsize Dear Receiver,

\lipsum[1-6]



        \normalsize Sender \leavevmode \\

        \small  Sender Address \leavevmode \\ \small

        Sender address etc \leavevmode \\ \small


\end{document}
```

Update on 27.01.2020

I was able to solve my problem using following code:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{zref-lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[ddmmmyyyy]{datetime} 


\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\LastPageNumber}{\zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{page}{0}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \ifnumcomp{\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}{>}{1}
    %for multiple pages header
    {{\fancyhead[C]{\ifthenelse{\value{page}=1}{First Page of Multiples}{Other pages of Multiples}}}}
    %for only one page
    {\fancyhead[C]{Single Page Header}
    } 
    \ifnumcomp{\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}{>}{1}
    %for multiple pages header
    {{
            \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
            \fancyfoot[C]{\ifnum\value{page}<\LastPageNumber
                \textit{Continue Multiple Pages}%
                \else
                \textit{Final Page End}
                \fi
             }}}
    %for only one page
    {\fancyfoot[C]{Single Page End}} 
    % If document is longer than 2 pages there will be page numeration, if not there will     not be.
    \lipsum[1-10] % automatically remove page number in a document with this line
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have been able to update and come to a solution.